# ReactJs Mixin not updating/sharing state

Tags: reactjs

Im new to the whole world of React JS.. I have two components which share functionality through a mixin. Its to handle a menu which opens and closes.. It works fine when i click the button and the state turn to true and false. Inside the second component I want to use the close function to close the menu when clicking on the shadow element. The state updates after calling the close function. But when click the button to open menu the state is still false..

Any ideas?

---Mixin---

```
var menuMixin = {

navIcon: $('#nav-icon'),
menu: $('#menu'),
htmlElement: $('html'),
header: $('header'),
getInitialState: function() {

    return {

        state: false

    };

},  
openMenu: function(){

    var THIS = this;    

    var $navIcon = $('#nav-icon'),  
        $menu = $('#menu'),
        $html = $('html'),
        $header = $('header');

    $menu.show();
    $navIcon.addClass('open');

    setTimeout(function(){

        THIS.switchLogo(true);
        $menu.addClass('active');
        $html.addClass('fixed');
        $header.removeClass('active'); 
        THIS.setState({state: true});

    }, 255);    

},

closeMenu: function() {

    var THIS = this;

    var $navIcon = $('#nav-icon'),  
        $menu = $('#menu'),
        $html = $('html'),
        $header = $('header');

    $menu.removeClass('active');
    $navIcon.removeClass('open');
    this.switchLogo(false);

    setTimeout(function(){

        $menu.hide();
        $html.removeClass('fixed');
        THIS.setState({state: false});

        if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 200 ) {

            $header.addClass('active');

        }

    }, 255);

}

};
```

--Nav Button--

```
var NavButton = React.createClass({
mixins:[logoSwitchlMixin, menuMixin],
handleClick: function() {

    console.log('handleClick -->' + this.state.state);

    if ( !this.state.state ) {

        this.openMenu();

    }
    else {

        this.closeMenu();

    }

},
render: function() {
    return (
        <button id="nav-button">
            <div id="nav-icon" onClick={this.handleClick} ref="icon">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
        </button>
    )
}

});
```

-- Sliding Menu --

```
var MainNav = React.createClass({

mixins:[logoSwitchlMixin, menuMixin],
scroll: function(target) {

    $('html, body').animate({

        scrollTop: $( '#'+ target ).offset().top

    }, 600);
},
scrollSection: function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    this.scroll( $(e.target).data('id') );

},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div id="menu" data-state="false">
            <div id="menu_wrapper">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a data-id="what" title="What We Do" alt="What We Do" onClick={this.scrollSection} >What We Do</a></li>
                        <li><a data-id="why" title="Why We Do It" alt="Why We Do It" onClick={this.scrollSection}>Why We Do It</a></li>
                        <li><a data-id="experiance" title="Our Experience" alt="Our Experience" onClick={this.scrollSection}>Our Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a data-id="how" title="How We Do It" alt="How We Do It" onClick={this.scrollSection}>How We Do It</a></li>
                        <li><a data-id="competence" title="Competence" alt="Competence" onClick={this.scrollSection}>Competence</a></li>
                        <li><a data-id="contact" title="Contact" alt="Contact" onClick={this.scrollSection}>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div onClick={this.closeMenu} id="shadow_blocker"></div>
        </div>
    );
}

});
ReactDOM.render(
   <MainNav />,
  document.getElementById('main-nav')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept of mixins is code reuse. The same code can be used with multiple components.

But you cant set state for the mixins like you did with menuMixin

The mixin once it is attached to a component and used inside a component will be auto binded with the component and the reference to the component(this) will be autobinded with the mixin function by react.

So you cant have state's to be shared from the mixin. But you can have reference to a dom element and so on but not state. And you can also modify a components state through the setState() method which will update properly, but the state should be present in the component and not in the mixin.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I have just added the state on the button element, and just grab the state from there..